# Интонационное тире после прямой речи в случаях, когда по общему правилу есть запятая

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, авторская-пунктуация

Пример из Розенталя:

> Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно», но глаза
> его блестят, полные зависти.

Я полагаю, что в подобных случаях автор может при желании использовать интонационное тире:

> Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно», — но
> глаза его блестят, полные зависти.

**Верно ли я полагаю?**

Comment: Это уже не интонационное тире, а единый знак получится. К тому же здесь не может быть интонационного тире в том смысле, как его обычно понимают.  Интонация такая же, как в предложении: Ко мне подходит Борис, хвалит меня, — но глаза его блестят, полные зависти. Будете ставить здесь тире (вернее, единый знак)?

Comment: @Sharon является ли вообще прямая речь членом предложения, и если да, то каким? Частью сказуемого? "Борис" — подлежащее, "подходит" и "говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно»" — два сказуемых? Или «Хорошо сбил, замечательно» — это дополнение?

Comment: @Sharon отвечая на ваш вопрос: я бы здесь поставил тире, если бы захотел отделить и/или подчеркнуть ту часть предложения, что после тире. Не знаю насчёт интонации, но пауза, обозначаемая запятой с тире звучит, на мой слух, длиннее, чем пауза, обозначаемая одной запятой.

Comment: Прямая речь здесь является прямой речью, но интонационно она оформляется как встроенная конструкция по образцу члена предложения.  Здесь "старшей" конструкцией является противопоставление с союзом НО, именно это мы должны выразить интонационно, а не делить предложение на части. У нас же там и двоеточие есть, будете делать после него увеличенную предупредительную паузу? Вот это и называется разделить предложение на части, не выразив главное. Впрочем, тема сложная, быстро ее не объяснишь. Это то место, до которого можно "доехать на поезде", а дальше строить "свою дорожку",

Comment: Никому и в голову не приходит, что оформление прямой речи по чисто формальным правилам в действительности  имеет определенный смысл. Не видя общей картины, лучше не изобретать ничего своего. Вас не поймут, но скажут, что вы нарушаете эти формальные правила.

Comment: @Sharon вы, думаю, заметили по вопросам, что я вообще любитель строить свои дорожки :) А прямая речь в кавычках, её положение относительно других членов предложения, пунктуационная и смысловая взаимосвязь — тема вообще, похоже, одна из наименее разработанных в справочниках, что Розенталя, что Лопатина.

Comment: Нам даны только правила безо  всяких объяснений. Вот в правилах говорится, что прямая речь должна быть повествовательной, а иначе тире надо ставить. А почему?  Объяснений нет. Тут надо учитывать уровень знаний в обществе. На первом уровне дается основа, а детали рассматриваются на втором уровне  (иначе важное перемешается с частным и не усвоится ничего). Но общество в целом и первый уровень никак не может освоить, вот в чем дело.